# Bullet list - verb or subject after a hyphenation

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation

I always wonder how to write bullet lists with a hyphenation.

> The “Actions” menu contains the following options:
>
> - Add role – it creates new role
> - Add role – creates new role

Can I start with a verb or do I need to add a subject? In the latter case it becomes flood with too much "it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should omit the "it" in a list like that.
Add role - creates a new role.
The subject is supplied by the phrase describing the menu item: "Add role".